# Custom post type archive URL

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a vanilla install of WP

Using Custom post type UI plugin I have added a CPT called 'news'.
Created some 'news' items and then looked in:

http://mysite.local/news/

Expecting to see an archive of all 'news' posts

Get a 404.

I can view an item fine: http://mysite.local/news/myitem

I have tried playing with various options for CPT but to no avail. One post said I needed to create a custom archive, but I'm pretty sure if none is specified then it will default to archive.php.

Comment: Did you set `has_archive` to `true` for your custom post type? Show us the code that registers the post type.

Comment: Using a plugin - will try and find code, but did try the archive to true and nada.

Comment: Settings are all in DB so can't see them.

Comment: You have to flush rewrite rules after making changes, not sure if that plugin does that for you. Honestly, post type registration is pretty trivial, code-wise, I suggest ditching the plugin and just doing it manually.

Comment: I did a clean install of WP and the problem has been resolved. Although I do have another issue which I will raise another question for in a mo - related so appreciate if you could take a look. thanks Milo.